# Would Like Open Source RSS / News Reader Code or Widget Python or Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, open-source, rss

I would like to be able to massage certain categories of news feeds to make their entries more consistent. For example, when a job seeker subscribes to two different job sites the feeds s/he gets will differ markedly. One would like to be able to perform lookups and other work in the news reader, process the incoming feed on the basis of any extra information found and then present the massaged job information to the user.

Have you seen any open source plug-ins, widgets or codes for news readers that invite modification?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a look at the Planet Venus software, which has a [filter system](http://intertwingly.net/code/venus/docs/filters.html) that might be useful for what you want.

Comment: Steven, thank you. With the filter system, that looks like just what I need. Beyond that, it looks like a solution to a problem involving aggregating numerous similar feeds from a single job site. Apologies for delay in responding. I haven't got used to stackoverflow.

Again, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is quite what you want, but you could look into [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/). You could also parse the feeds with [PyRSS2Gen](http://www.dalkescientific.com/Python/PyRSS2Gen.html).

Comment: Thanks for responding, Kiv. I was familiar with PyRSS2Gen, couldn't see how to make it work. I had actually tried Yahoo Pipes but what I need to do would, I think, inevitably result in too much load for them. Apologies for delay in responding. Not used to stackoverflow yet.

Comment: No problem, glad you found what you were looking for :) It was helpful to me too, I didn't know about Planet Venus and it looks really neat.

Answer (score 0):

I'd still be interested in any responses that people might have to my question. However, in case anyone sees the question and is also looking for something like this, let me mention the existence of [rawdog](http://offog.org/code/rawdog.html).

A claim made at that link is that, "rawdog is an RSS Aggregator Without Delusions Of Grandeur."